# I am trying to host a project I built on two separate repositories

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I have a MEAN stack project that is built on two separate repositories. The backend is using Node.js and handles all API routing to MongoDB Atlas. If i wanted to host this on something like firebase, how would I go about that? I am not sure of any way to do this and haven't found similar scenarios such as this online.

This is an example of one of the components from the frontend.

The html file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FamilyService } from '../family.service';
import { IncomeService } from '../income.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-income',
  templateUrl: './income.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./income.component.scss']
})
export class IncomeComponent implements OnInit {
  date: any;
  family: any;
  amount: any;
  Incomes: any = [];
  Families: any = [];



  constructor(private router: Router, private familyService: FamilyService, private incomeService: IncomeService) {

    this.date = new Date().toDateString();
    this.family = ""
    this.amount = ""


   }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFamilies()
    this.getIncomes()
  }

  createNewIncome(){
    let request = {
      family:  this.family,
      amount: this.amount,
      Date: this.date
    }
    console.log(request.family);
    this.incomeService.createIncome(request).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.getIncomes()
    });
  }

  getFamilies(){
    let familyInfo:any = []
    this.familyService.getFamily().subscribe((res: any) => {
     let arr = res
     arr.forEach((family: any) => {
      // console.log(element)
      if(family.status == "active"){
        familyInfo.push(family)

      }
     });

    });

    console.log(familyInfo);
    this.Families = familyInfo
  }

  getIncomes(){
    let incomeInfo:any = []
    this.incomeService.getIncome().subscribe((res: any) => {
     let arr = res
     arr.forEach((element: any) => {
      // console.log(element)

       incomeInfo.push(element)
     });

    });

    console.log(incomeInfo);
    this.Incomes = incomeInfo
  }

  goToPage(PageName:string):void{


    this.router.navigate([`${PageName}`]);
    // else
    // outterrormessage
  }

  addEntry():void{
    console.log(this.date + " " + this.family + " " + this.amount)
    let entry = {
      Date: this.date,
      family: this.family,
      amount: this.amount
    }

    this.Incomes.push(entry)
    console.log(this.Incomes)
  }

  deleteEntry(entry:any):void {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you would like to delete this entry?")){
      this.incomeService.deleteIncome(entry._id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.getIncomes() // Once the record gets deleted we refetch
      })
    }
    
  }
  updateEntry(entry:any):void {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you would like to update this entry?")){
      this.incomeService.updateIncome(entry._id, entry).subscribe((res:any) => {
        this.getIncomes() // After the record gets edited we refetch
     })
   }
  }
  toggleEditEntry(entry:any){
    entry.isEditing = !entry.isEditing;
  }
}
```

The service.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FamilyService } from '../family.service';
import { IncomeService } from '../income.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-income',
  templateUrl: './income.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./income.component.scss']
})
export class IncomeComponent implements OnInit {
  date: any;
  family: any;
  amount: any;
  Incomes: any = [];
  Families: any = [];



  constructor(private router: Router, private familyService: FamilyService, private incomeService: IncomeService) {

    this.date = new Date().toDateString();
    this.family = ""
    this.amount = ""


   }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFamilies()
    this.getIncomes()
  }

  createNewIncome(){
    let request = {
      family:  this.family,
      amount: this.amount,
      Date: this.date
    }
    console.log(request.family);
    this.incomeService.createIncome(request).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.getIncomes()
    });
  }

  getFamilies(){
    let familyInfo:any = []
    this.familyService.getFamily().subscribe((res: any) => {
     let arr = res
     arr.forEach((family: any) => {
      // console.log(element)
      if(family.status == "active"){
        familyInfo.push(family)

      }
     });

    });

    console.log(familyInfo);
    this.Families = familyInfo
  }

  getIncomes(){
    let incomeInfo:any = []
    this.incomeService.getIncome().subscribe((res: any) => {
     let arr = res
     arr.forEach((element: any) => {
      // console.log(element)

       incomeInfo.push(element)
     });

    });

    console.log(incomeInfo);
    this.Incomes = incomeInfo
  }

  goToPage(PageName:string):void{


    this.router.navigate([`${PageName}`]);
    // else
    // outterrormessage
  }

  addEntry():void{
    console.log(this.date + " " + this.family + " " + this.amount)
    let entry = {
      Date: this.date,
      family: this.family,
      amount: this.amount
    }

    this.Incomes.push(entry)
    console.log(this.Incomes)
  }

  deleteEntry(entry:any):void {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you would like to delete this entry?")){
      this.incomeService.deleteIncome(entry._id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.getIncomes() // Once the record gets deleted we refetch
      })
    }
    
  }
  updateEntry(entry:any):void {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you would like to update this entry?")){
      this.incomeService.updateIncome(entry._id, entry).subscribe((res:any) => {
        this.getIncomes() // After the record gets edited we refetch
     })
   }
  }
  toggleEditEntry(entry:any){
    entry.isEditing = !entry.isEditing;
  }
}
```

The web service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebRequestService {
  //Root URL wrapped in constant
  readonly ROOT_URL;

  //Returns http method observables
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.ROOT_URL = `http://localhost:3000`;
  }
  //Getting one
  get(uri: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }
  //Creating one
  post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }
  //Updating one
  patch(uri: string, payload: Object) { 
    return this.http.patch(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
  }
  //Deleting one
  delete(uri: string) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
  }
}
```

This is my first time working with Angular and a MEAN stack so I apologize for the poor programming practices here.If you need I can also upload the backend code: routes, models, and service files.

Comment: I'm not sure what being in two seperate repositories has to do with this. You've got an app that you wanted hosted (or several apps). What's stopping you from being able to do that?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I guess I'm just not sure how to do it in a way that a user, with no programming experience, would be able to just view the app online. Would I have to host each repository individually?

Comment: When you say repository, do you mean a Git repository?

Comment: Yes, they are both on Github

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).